# Scraping URLs from webpage to further scrape single URLs from that first scrape (re-using URL from scraped data)

Tags: r, web-scraping, tidyverse, rvest

I am scraping data from different movie franchises on IMDB. As IMDB provides franchises as a list, I first scrape the list of let's say "Jurassic Park".

```
library(rvest)

page <- read_html("https://www.imdb.com/list/ls020374215/")

Names <- page %>% html_nodes(".lister-item-header a") %>% html_text('')

Titles <- (page %>% html_nodes(".lister-item-header a") %>% html_attr('href'))
Titles <- gsub("/title/","https://www.imdb.com/title/", Titles)

dataset <- data.frame(cbind(Names, Titles))
```

Now, I want to scrape from the URLs of the single movies in the dataframe "dataset"

Worldwide Gross, Budget, Year, Title

```
Gross <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="titleDetails"]/div[10]/text()' ) %>% html_text('')
Budget <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="titleDetails"]/div[7]/text()' ) %>% html_text('')
Year <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="titleYear"]/a' ) %>% html_text('')
Title <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="title-overview-widget"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/h1/text()' ) %>% html_text('')
```

I tried to extract the URLs one by one to store them as a new "page" variable with this

```
page <- as.character(data.frame(test[1, 3])) #selecting first row, 3rd column to retrieve URL
```

but this always yields "Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") :
nicht anwendbare Methode für 'xml_find_all' auf Objekt der Klasse "character" angewendet"

Any Ideas?
Also open for feedback if this process is totally idiotic.

Comment: Your xpaths don't seem right  to me. I tested first few against the webpage with/without javascript running and no matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the code from each page individually with some kind of loop. Write a function.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

dataset <- data.frame(Names, Titles)

return_data <- function(url) {
  page <- url %>% read_html 
  tibble(Gross = page %>%
                    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="titleDetails"]/div[10]') %>%
                    html_text(trim = TRUE) %>%
                    parse_number(), 
         Budget = page %>% 
                    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="titleDetails"]/div[7]') %>% 
                    html_text(trim = TRUE) %>% 
                    parse_number(), 
         Year =   page %>% 
                    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="titleYear"]/a' ) %>% 
                    html_text(trim = TRUE) %>% 
                    parse_number(), 
         Title = page %>% 
                    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="title-overview-widget"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/h1') %>%
                    html_text(trim = TRUE))
}
```

Now use `map_df` to extract data from each link and combine the datasets.

```
result <- cbind(dataset, map_df(dataset$Titles, return_data))
result

#                           Names
#1                  Jurassic Park
#2                 Jurassic World
#3 Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom
#4  The Lost World: Jurassic Park
#5              Jurassic Park III
#                                                 Titles      Gross    Budget Year
#1 https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107290/?ref_=ttls_li_tt 1033928303  63000000 1993
#2 https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0369610/?ref_=ttls_li_tt 1670516444 150000000 2015
#3 https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4881806/?ref_=ttls_li_tt 1310464680 170000000 2018
#4 https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119567/?ref_=ttls_li_tt  618638999  73000000 1997
#5 https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0163025/?ref_=ttls_li_tt  368780809  93000000 2001
#                                  Title
#1                  Jurassic Park (1993)
#2                 Jurassic World (2015)
#3 Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom (2018)
#4  The Lost World: Jurassic Park (1997)
#5              Jurassic Park III (2001)
```

Comment: That's strange. Are you running on the same data that you shared? I just tried it again and it works for me and returns the same output as shown in my answer.

Comment: @TomTe It seems you are on R < 4.0.0 Use `dataset <- data.frame(Names, Titles, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` and try the answer again.